# Inserting in a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, insert, linked-list, runtime-error

Please help me with my code. I am trying to insert in a singly linked list.My code is compiling but it is giving a run time error.I am not able to understand where i have gone wrong.Here goes my code :-

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
  int info;
  struct node* next;
};

typedef struct node* nodeptr;

void insert(nodeptr p,int x);
void print(nodeptr p);

int main()
{
    nodeptr head;
    head = NULL;
    int num;
    do
    {
        cout<<"ENTER A NUMBER(0 to terminate) :-\n";
        cin >>num;
        insert(head,num);
    }
    while (num != 0);
    print(head);
}

void insert(nodeptr p,int x)
{
    nodeptr tmp = new node;
    tmp -> info = x;
    tmp -> next = NULL;
    nodeptr current;
    current = p;

    if (p == NULL)
    {
         p = tmp;
    }
    if (x < p -> info)
    {
        tmp->next = p;
        p = tmp;
    }

    while((current->next != NULL) && (x >= (current->next)->info))
        {
            current = current -> next;
        }
    tmp->next = current->next;
    current->next = tmp;


}
void print(nodeptr p)
{
    nodeptr current;
    current = p;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        int tmp = current->info;
        cout << tmp;
        current = current->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Classic problem of passing a parameter (p) to a function (insert) which then assigns a value to p (the new node), but doesn't return anything. On returning from the first call to insert(), the value of p won't have changed, it will still be NULL. You need to modify insert() to return a pointer to the node it created, or find out the difference between call-by-value and call-by-reference parameters.

Comment: Are you doing it as an exercise? Otherwise, there is no need to implement a singly-linked list on your own, `std::forward_list` does the job.

Comment: Also, you are not cleaning up your memory anywhere. It's good practice to clean up your memory when you do not need it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you never assign anything to head, so print(head) will not print anything.

Second, that last while in the main is useless.

Third:

```
nodeptr insert(nodeptr head, int x)
{
        nodeptr tmp = new node;
        tmp -> info = x;
        tmp -> next = NULL;

        nodeptr prec = null;
        nodeptr current = head;


        while(current != null && x < current->info)
        {
                prec = current;
                current = current -> next;
        }
        tmp->next = current;

        if(prec != null) 
            prec->next = tmp;
        else
            return tmp;

        return head;
}
```

and in the main

```
head = insert(head, num);
```

When dealing with pointers, always try to keep things separated: first seek, then modify.